# inline code to change bg image for css-sprite

Tags: javascript, html, css

### I've found the answer by myself and posted it below.

I'm trying to implement a css sprite. And I would like to change a specific image's background (pointed to a css sprite) by hover, while using in-line code.

I tried this, it didn't work.

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP//////zCH5BAEHAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
width="100" height="105"
style="background:url(y.png);hover{background:url('y.png') -20px -20px;">
```

I also tried this, onmouseover/out function but no avail:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP//////zCH5BAEHAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" width="100" height="105" style="background:url(x.png);"
onmouseover="background: url(y.png) -47px -45px;"
onmouseout="bg.src='x.png'">
```

I also tried above without css sprite position, still doesn't work.

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP//////zCH5BAEHAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" width="100" height="105" style="background:url(x.png);"
onmouseover="bg.src='y.png';"
onmouseout="bg.src='x.png'">
```

And at last, I tried this:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP//////zCH5BAEHAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
width="100" height="105"
style="background:url(x.png);"
onmouseover="this.style.background='y.png'"
onmouseout="this.style.background='x.png'">
```

For my own reasons, I would like to do the css-sprite image hover thing with in-line code.

Comment: onmouseover="this.style.backgroundImage='url(x.png)' -20px -20px;"
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundImage='url(y.png)';" changes the image but coordinates doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

So if you are using the `img` tag I don't think it make sense to target the background... what you need to do is to change the source of your image...

1) Css won't work as you can't do a `:hover` state inline.. so you need javascript.

try this

```html
  <img src="http://www.guitarworld.com/sites/default/files/public/styles/article_detail_featured__622x439_/public/dimebag_2_3.jpg"width="200" height="205" onmouseover='this.src = "http://www.metalinjection.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/dimebag-darrell.jpg"' 
    onmouseout='this.src = "http://www.guitarworld.com/sites/default/files/public/styles/article_detail_featured__622x439_/public/dimebag_2_3.jpg"'/>
```

just replace the image sources for your won and you'll see the image change... is that what you want right???.

Comment: I'm trying to implemet CSS Sprites. Multiple images in a single file. Simple [onmouseover / onmouseout this.src=] is not enough for me.

Comment: As far as I found, [onmouseover / onmouseout this.style.background=...] was what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my own problem.

The magical phrase is this: "this.style.background='url(sprite.png) -100px -100px';"

The code required was this:

```
<img src="transparent-placeholder.png"
width="100" height="100" style="background:url(sprite.png) 0px -100px;"
onmouseover="this.style.background='url(sprite.png) -100px -100px';"
onmouseout="this.style.background='url(sprite.png) 0px -100px';">
```